# I have a list of 35,000 names of companiess. I need to perform an internet search and return the url of the first result .

Tags: vba, url, automation

I have a list of 35,000 names of companies. I need to perform an internet search and return the first result . I would like to automate the process. I was orginally thinking about using IE automation in excel. However, I am not sure if there is a better approach. I need to google search the company's name and return the URL of the first result. If the results could be in excel, that would be great as the list is in excel. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can do it using VBA and IE.  "better" is pretty subjective and depends on your skill level in VBA vs. other technologies/languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate IE to perform the search. Normally, a delay is set up to keep checking if the page is loaded. I suggested recently that a better alternative is to keep trying to reference the first H3 element in the page, and read it's contained A-tags' href attribute. If this succeeds then Stop navigating the page, or navigate to the next page.

There is a slight catch with this approach though, as the H3 is often a sponsored-link. It is possible to determine this though, and so find a link further down.

The whole process will still take an age though.

Alternatively, there is the [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) but you'll have to pay for more then 100 searches per day.